# What is an example of a local class outliving its method?

Tags: java

What would be an example of an instance of a local class outliving its method?
Seeing the local class/datatype is only visible within that method,
what should be the datatype of a variable supposed to store the reference to the local class instance?
Where should such local classes (with instances outliving their methods) be used?

Comment: Are you talking about anonymous classes? Please add code.

Answer (score 4):

One example would be a local class implementing [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)/[Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and then being sent to an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) e.g.:

```
public void sendMailAsync(Message msg){

   class MailSendingRunnable implements Runnable(){

       private MailSender mailSender;
       private Message msg;

       public MailSendingRunnable(Message msg, MailSender mailSender){
           // ...
       }

       public void run(){
           mailSender.send(msg);
       }

   }

   this.executor.submit(new MailSendingRunnable(this.mailSender, msg);
}
```

As you can see, the MailSendingRunnable will live after the method returns because the method run in MailSendingRunnable will be called later in another thread as the [ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable,%20T%29) method states.